# Table of contents appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

My table of contents looks like this now:

> A Appendix A
>
> B Appendix B
>
> C Appendix C
>
> D Appendix D

I want it to look like this:

> Appendix A
>
> Appendix B
>
> Appendix C
>
> Appendix D

I use the following code to make the appendices:

```
\chapter{Appendix A} \label{App:AppendixA}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
```

I tried the following:

```
\chapter*{Appendix A}
\label{App:AppendixA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}
```

This does however give me the correct result ***in the table of contents***. But the problem here is that when using the first code, I get the following result: [image: GoodAppendix].

But when I then use the code as I explained above, I get the following result:
[image: BadAppendix]

I obviously want the big letters to remain.

Comment: Please provide a complete, compilable, minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using the report or a similar class. If that be the case, you can make use of the `appendix` package by adding this simple command to the preamble

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
```

The `appendices` environment then does your work, where you can simply use the `\chapter` command and provide a suitable title to your appendix. For example:

```
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Code for Numerical Simulation}
%the first appendix
text for this appendix goes here
\end{appendices}
```

In table of contents, it appears as follows
[image: appendices in table of contents]

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, as in your example it still says "A Code for Numerical Simulation". My question is, how do I remove the A in front?